# Disabling pasting completely in [contenteditable] div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm having the luck of having to work with multiple contenteditable divs instead of textareas. I fixed almost everything, but can't find a way to completely disable pasting into the div:

```
$(document).on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The paste-event does fire, but the text still gets pasted. This only has to work on Chrome (latest). Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to return false

```js
$(document).on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works in jsfiddle but not on my project.. going to figure it out and post back!

Comment: solved, I forgot I used 'Mediumeditor' for headings and such, which overrode my code. Solved via: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/1205#issuecomment-278227148

Answer (score 1):

try to change `document` with `div`

```
$('div').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```